# Не добавляются (просматривает) данные в таблицу mysql в phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста! Не добавляются данные в таблицу, хотя на странице пишет что данные успешно добавлены. В phpmyadmin не доступен раздел Browse пишет что пусто. В чем дело не пойму?
таблица имеет 5 колонок

```
 GREATE TABLE guitarwars (
 date DATETIME ,
 name VARCHAR (30) ,
 score DEC (10,0)
 screenshot  VARCHAR (64) );
```

Потом добавил id.

```
<?php
//Инициализация константы,  содержащие имя каталога
//Для загружаемых файлов изображений
define('GW_UPLOADPATH', 'images/');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//извлечение данных из суперглобального массива $_POST
$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];
$screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];

if (!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)) {
    //перемещение файла в постоянный каталог для файлов изображений
    $target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot'] ['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    //соединение с базой данных
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'r0058300_arty21');

    //Запись данных в базу данных
    $query = "INSERT INTO guitarwars VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score' '$screenshot')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    //Вывод пользователю потверждения в получении данных
    echo '<p>Спасибо за то, что добавили свой новый рейтинг!</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ' . $name . '<br/>';
    echo '<strong>Рейтинг:</strong> ' . $score . '<br/>';
    echo '<img src"' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot . '"
    alt="Изображение , подтверждающее подлиность рейтинга" /><p />';
    echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Назад к списку рейтингов</a></p>';

    //Очистка полей ввода данных формы
    $name = "";
    $score = "";
    $screenshot = "";

    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
else {
    echo '<p class="error">Введите, пожалуйста, всю информацию, 
    необходимую ' . 'для добавления вашего рейтинга.</p>';
}
```

}

}
?>

У меня подозрение что проблемы с этой частью кода

```
$query = "INSERT INTO guitarwars VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score' '$screenshot')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проверить само подключение и запуск запроса: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Подозреваю проблема в подключении к базе.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    /* Note, that we can't execute any functions which interact with the
       server until result set was closed. All calls will return an
       'out of sync' error */
    if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с подключением, выше вам уже ответили.

Comment: ответ можно было оставить )

Comment: но при добавлении информации страница не ругается на подключение, а наоборот пишет что все ok данные добавлены. Если бы были проблемы с подключением тогда по логике браузер ругался бы! Или я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO guitarwars (date, name, score, screenshot, approved)
                 VALUES (NOW(), '$name', '$score', '$screenshot', 0)";
```